# Should I use EXISTS or IN

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables:

1. `Foo` with 24.000.000 rows
2. `Bar` with 16 rows

I'm considering rewriting query

```
SELECT * FROM Foo as F
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Bar as B WHERE B.Baz = F.Baz)
```

with this one

```
SELECT * FROM Foo
WHERE Baz IN (SELECT Baz FROM Bar)
```

Edit: A third option was suggested in the comments. I didn't consider joining because I don't need any columns from Bar

```
SELECT * FROM Foo as F
JOIN Bar as B on B.Baz = F.Baz
```

But after looking at the execution plans for both queries I couldn't spot the difference. Are these queries really equivalent?  **Which query is better?**

What should I consider when deciding between `EXISTS` and `IN`. I was wondering if SQL Server is smart enough to execute the nested query once and store the result for comparison, or does it execute the nested query for each row?

Comment: How about `SELECT Foo.* FROM Foo JOIN Bar ON Bar.Baz=Foo.Baz`?

Comment: I would use `EXISTS` but not for performance reasons, read this: [Should I use NOT IN, OUTER APPLY, LEFT OUTER JOIN, EXCEPT, or NOT EXISTS?](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) I assume it is also true for `EXISTS/IN`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I was just looking for this link from a previous answer of yours. Lucky me you happened to drop in.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson In the real query I have 8 EXISTS statemens. Repacing them with joins slowed down the query several times

Comment: @TimSchmelter - `EXISTS` and `IN` get the same plan.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - That is not the same semantics. `EXISTS` is a semi join not an inner join. The `JOIN` can bring back duplicates.

Comment: @MartinSmith: as i've mentioned "not for performance reasons". From link above: "_The main problem is that the results can be surprising if the target column is NULLable (SQL Server processes this as a left anti semi join, but can't reliably tell you if a NULL on the right side is equal to – or not equal to – the reference on the left side). Also, optimization can behave differently if the column is NULLable, even if it doesn't actually contain any NULL values_"

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I'm well aware of that. [My answer here looks at that in detail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists/11074428#11074428) That only applies to the `NOT` versions.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, `DISTINCT` is needed for the same result, I was more interested in whether the query plan with a join was different in any significant way. I suspect it's not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either `EXISTS` or `IN` are fine.

Both should give you the [same plan](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/08/17/exists-vs-in/) with a logical semi join operator (`NULL` does not change the semantics here unlike `NOT IN`/`NOT EXISTS`)

Replacing with an `INNER JOIN` could change the results except if `Baz` is guaranteed to be unique in `Bar`.

Without this constraint an inner join could bring back additional rows that you would then need to get rid of with `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be the same as well but less confusing? The scenario you describe lends itself to an inner join.

```
SELECT F.* FROM Foo as F inner join Bar as B on F.Baz=B.Baz
```